# default web.xml in maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web.xml

I am newly using maven,by defalut at the time of creating maven web application project the following web.xml is created.

```
     !DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
     "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
     "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

    <web-app>

     .........
     .........
    </web-app>
```

but every time I am changing the above web.xml to like this

```
<web-app id="AppName" 
         version="2.4" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    ...

</web-app>
```

so can anyone tell me how to get this above web.xml while creating project,I am using eclipse to create maven project.